# Startup page on Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to set the first page to load in my meteor app, depending on whether the user is registered or not. (If user isn't logged-in load the x template, otherwise load the signIn template).

The issue I have is that my sign-in template have links to other templates (Recovery password and sign-up) which are not working (the page always stay in sign-in template probably by my "if currentUser" clause).  Probably I'm approaching it in a wrong way.

Any idea how to set the first page to load?  This is my html:

```
<template name="main">
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{> header}}
    {{> yield}}
  {{else}}
    {{> entrySignUp}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="home">
  {{#if eventJoined}}
    {{> board}}
  {{else}}
    {{> findEvent}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

These are my routes.  Myapp.js:

```
Router.route ('/home')
Router.route('/', { template: 'home'});
Router.configure({layoutTemplate: 'main'});
Router.route('/findEvent');
Router.route('/board');
```

Comment: Can you please add your route codes and all the related codes? The issue is probably you have your {{> yield}} for only currentUser. Iron:router needs a {{> yield}} to render the rest of the routes/templates.

Comment: Ok, I already edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which route renders which template like this:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'mainTemplateName',
    loadingTemplate: 'loadingTempName'
});

Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/another-route', function() {
    this.render('anotherTemplate');
});
```

Any of those templates will render to {{> yield}} so, if you have it inside `if currentUser`, it won't be able to render those for non-users.

**EDIT**

Your main/layout template should contain the main elements of the layout like navigation bar, footer, sidebar etc. They only render once when the user enters the site. {{> yield}} specifies where the rest of the templates should render when the user goes to other routes, without changing/re-rendering the elements in layout/main template

**EDIT-2**
In your main template, you have this:

```
{{#if currentUser}}
  {{> header}}
  {{> yield}}
{{else}}
  {{> entrySignUp}}
{{/if}}
```

which means the `{{> yield}}` for iron:router is only for logged in users. You need the yield to be for all visitors so that the users can go to other routes/iron router can render other templates like recover password/signup as you wrote in your question. So, include the `{{> yield}}` outside of `{{#if currentUser}}` and use it wherever else its necessary. For example:

Main template:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{> navigation}}

    <div class="content-area">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="navigation">
    This will always be visible in every route according to the template above.
</template>
```

You can also do a check in your router.js to determine what to render like this:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
    if(Meteor.user()){
        this.render('someTemplate') //for logged in user in route '/'
    } else {
        this.render('entrySignUp');
    }
});

Router.route('/findEvent');
Router.route('/board');
```

In this case, no matter which route you go, the templates above will always render to `{{> yield}}`, not depending on if its a user or not but {{> yield}} should be available for both logged in and logged out users for iron router to actually have a place to render templates for none-users, in your case.

Comment: Actually I have correspondence between my routes names and my templates names (Route/template have the same name), that's why Iron Router don't need I be specific in the render clause.     I'm not clear with your answer if I need to do changes in the HTML or delete the `#if currentUser`

Comment: {{> yield}} is the place where iron:router renders the templates. You tell iron router to render it for currentUser. Thats wrong. Yield should be both current user and non-users. Its the place iron:router renders ANY template for anyone so yes, you should change your html.

Comment: @Ruben Okay updated my answer. Please note that I didn't write the codes with the exact template names/structure you have.

Comment: there is a way the layout template don't load for sing-in and sign-out templates?

Comment: your main template always loads but you can hide the parts of it with if currentUser. you don't have to have everything inside currentUser block. For example, if you wrap {{> navigation}} from my example inside {{#if currentUser}}, visiter can go to routes but navigation will only be visible to logged in users.

Comment: I got it!  Thank you.